# PHP Call outside class function inside anonymous function

Tags: php, class, anonymous

hey guys i wanna call my function inside class A than call it inside class B within anonymous function how to do that ?
here my sample code.

```
<?php

     class A extends Z{
        public function sampleFunction($post){
           // code here
        }

     }

     class B extends A{
       public __construct(){
         $this->anotherClass();
       }
    // add_action() and update_meta_box() is function from wordpress

       public function anotherClass(){
         $post = $_POST['test'];
         add_action('save_post',function($id){
           if(isset($post)){
    // here i dont know how to call it inside anonymous function
             $this->sampleFunction($post); 
             update_meta_box(
               $id,
               'key',
               strip_tags($post)
             );
           }
         });
       }

     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Which version of php are you using?

Comment: yah.. getting error like this `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context` i'm using PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `use ($post)` to make it accessible within the anonymous function.

```
public function anotherClass(){
    $post = $_POST['test'];
    add_action('save_post', function($id) use ($post) {
        if(isset($post)) {
            $this->sampleFunction($post);
            update_meta_box($id, 'key', strip_tags($post));
        }
    });
}
```

Also, if you are using php 5.3, you cannot use `$this` within the function. You need to use

```
$that = $this;
add_action(...) use ($post, $that) {
    //...
    $that->sampleFunction(...)
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, already try that and it's working, so if i wanna use `$` from another string or variable i must using `use` ? btw i getting new error `Fatal error: Call to a member function resetParameters() on a non-object` i'm using zend gdata inside wordpress plugin.